# ¿por que me da esos valores de undefined?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

soy principiantes y la cuestian es que debo poder colocar un nuevo elemento en el array en el indice que se me indica, sin eliminar otro, y creo que tenia la respuesta, usando un ciclo para hacer para copiar los ultimos datos despues del index introducido (si es que hay), luego cambia la lngitud para borrar los datos, luego agrego el nuevo elemento en el index indicado, y luego uso un segundo ciclo para colocar los datos copias, (la cuestion es que no debo usar ningun metodo de arrays), ni shift, ni pop, ni unshift, nada de eso.

```
var array = []; /*array principal el cual se necesita cambiar constantemente*/
var cicloApp = true;
while(cicloApp){ /*comienzo del ciclo principal*/
    var cicloElemnto = true
    while(cicloElemnto){ /*ciclo para la validacion de los elementos a agregar*/
        var elemento = prompt("Indique el elemento que desea agregar");

        if(elemento == '' || elemento == null){
            alert("El campo esta vacio, intente de nuevo");
        }
            else(cicloElemnto = false);
    }

    var cicloIndex = true/*ciclo para la validacion del index para la posicion deseada a agregar*/
    while(cicloIndex){
        var index = prompt("indique la posicion en la que desea colocar el nuevo elemento");

        if(index == '' || index == null){
            alert("caracter invalido");
        }
            else if(isNaN(index)){
                alert("carcter invalido");
            }
                else if(index > array.length || index < 0){
                    alert("posicion invalida");
                }
                    else(cicloIndex = false);
            }
    var elementos = []
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){/*ciclo de iteracon del array principal para copiar los elementos despues del index introducido, al array elementos*/
        elementos[i] = array[i];
    }
    
    array[index] = elemento; /*introduccion del nuevo elemento*/
    
    for(var i = index+1; i < elemento.length; i++){ /*ciclo de iteracion con la finalidad de intrudicir nuevamente los valores copidos despues de agregar el nuevo elemento*/
        array[i] = elementos[i];
    }
    
    console.log(elementos);
    console.log(array)
    if(!confirm("Agregar otro emelento?")){ /*confirmacion para salir del ciclo principal*/
        cicloApp = false;
            }
}
```

Comment: Comienza arreglando el error que la variable `array` no existe.

Comment: uy perdon no se copio pero si esta definida en el codigo original ya lo edito

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo lo siguiente:

Cuando insertas, divides en 2 el array original a partir del index de inserción. Entonces

0. Lo de la izquierda permanece igual
1. Se guarda lo que está a la derecha
2. Se inserta el valor en el índice
3. Se inserta lo guardado en el  punto (1) a la derecha

```js
Array.prototype.insert = function(item,index){
  //si el índice no está dentro de los margenes
  if(index<0 || this.length<index) return;
  let arrayAux = [];

  //Guardamos lo de la derecha
 
  for(let i = index, conta = 0; i < this.length; i++,conta++){
    arrayAux[conta] = this[i];
  }

  //Agregamos el valor en su índice
  this[index] = item;

  //Agregamos lo que habiamos guardado anterorimente
  for(let i=0; i < arrayAux.length; i++){
    this[index+i+1] = arrayAux[i];
  }
}

let arrayprueba = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];

//insertamos el ítem 7 en el índice 3
arrayprueba.insert(7,3);

console.log(arrayprueba);
```

Comment: gracias, creo que ya vi el problema, aunque no puedo usar push creo que puedo cambiarlo :D de verdad muchas gracias

Comment: @Alastor Ahí lo edité sin el push

Comment: gracias voy a tratar de implementarlo ya que aun no llego al manjo de las funciones pero creo que logro entender un poco, si no me funciona capaz vuelvo llorando a ti, gracias por la amabilidad :D

Comment: bueno volvi llorando, alli subi el nuevo codigo intentado aplicar lo que me explicaste peor me sigue dando undifined, creo que no te logre entender, perdon :C

Comment: @Alastor Primero establezcamos un par de puntos, que debería pasar cuando tienes el arreglo vacío y quieres agregar en el índice 5???

Comment: nada, si el index indicado es mayor a la longitud del arreglo deberia decirte que es invalido y pedir que intruduzcas otro index, esta en las validaciones de la intruduccion del index, no puede ser mayor a la longitud del arreglo

Comment: me explico, comienzo a pedir el elemento a agregar, siempre y cuando no este vacio, luego el index, el cual pido que no este vacio tampoco, que verifique que sea un numero, y por ultimo que no sea mayor a la longitud del arreglo principal, luego creo un array para copiar al arreglo principal, agregar el elemento en el index indicado, y que remplaze y coloque los elementos copiados despues del nuevo elemento segun el index indicado, pero me da el valor, como con 5 undifined mas